# adjusting height properties of scrollview within linear layout

Tags: android, xml, listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a layout for an item in my listview. My problem is with the scroll view. The comments textview which I am storing inside can vary in length anywhere from 2 words to 255 characters. This creates a problem in my listview as when there is little text present it leaves a huge gap with the current setup. I don't want to get rid of the weight system as it is very helpful with all the other items in my layout,however I do not know how to use it here so that the height of the scrollview wraps around the content and doesn't take up more space then necessary. I've tried setting a fixed height for my scrollview as well as getting rid of the weighting for it, and using wrap content, however wrap content doesn't work when there is a large amount of text. To summarise, when there is little text I'm left with a huge gap, when there is a lot of text, if I use wrap content it will fill up the whole screen and ruin the whole point of using a scrollview to save space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="220dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="250">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/leaguetxt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="English Premier League"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datetxt"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="BET UNTIL : 23/05/2015 15:00 GMT"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="35">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamstxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Sevilla FC - FC Barcelona"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->


    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/bettxt"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:text="FC Barcelona Win and BTTS"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:textStyle="" />





</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="DIFFICULTY : "
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_weight="50"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/difficultytxt"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:text="MEDIUM RISK"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/commenttxt"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:text = ""/>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/oddsbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="SelectBet"
        android:text="3.60"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a ScrollView inside a list item. It will cause glitches when scrolling the list because you would be scrolling both the list and the Scroll view of you item. And it will also cause problem calculating the height of you scrollview such as the one you seem to be experiencing.

I think you should make you comment block to wrap_content and modify your layout to get rid of your layout_weight. If you don't want to always display long comments, you could elipsize them at a certain length and add a button to show/hide full comment.